# Set default value for column in Mosaic Decisions

Tags: mosaic-decisions

I’m using a data flow in Mosaic Decisions and I’m using a MySQL writer node. The result set that I’m going to write has a field `inserted-time`. But I want to skip the value in this column and want to use the default value set for that column in the DB table. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply drag the column that you want to skip into the "skip-insert-column" section of the writer node.

[image]

In this screenshot for example, the column "Target" will not be inserted into the target table and whatever default value set for that column in the DB table will be applied automatically.